# C language reading from file and placing in variables

Tags: c, file, txt

In a text file I have the form Type:Username Password, how do I place it in three different variables, so that the variable Type is in the variable type, username is in username, and password is in password in C ?

Example:

```
Admin:Username Password
```

How to make?

```
Type:Admin
User:Username 
Pw:Password
```

Here's my code:

```
int ch;
int i = 0;
while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    // Check for the colon character
    if (ch == ':') {
        // We have reached the end of the type string
        // Move to the next variable
        i = 0;
        continue;
    }
    // Check for the space character
    if (ch == ' ') 
    {
        // We have reached the end of the username string
        // Move to the next variable
        i = 0;
        continue;
    }
    // Store the character in the appropriate variable
    if (i < 50) {
        if (type[0] == 0) {
            type[i] = ch;
        } else if (username[0] == 0) {
            username[i] = ch;
        } else {
            password[i] = ch;
        }
        i++;

    }
}
```

Comment: hint: read the whole line with `fgets()`, then use `sscanf()` or parse the line with stuff like `strchr()` or even `strtok()`. There are a lot of possibilities, so you might just want to play around and try them out

Comment: Review the `continue` statement.  Using it you don't reach the bottom part of the loop, where you store the value.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your initial requirement that you posted in your Question, that a text file consists of following line:

> Admin:Username Password

To store Admin in variable `type`, Username in variable `username` and similarly Password in variable `Password`.
You can declare a `structure` something similar to:

```
typedef struct user {
    char type[512];
    char username[512];
    char password[512];
} user;
```

And as @IngoLeonhardt commented, that `strtok()` or `strchr()` can be used to parse the line read from the text file, you can refer the below simple example code snippet to understand and further improve the logic.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct user {
    char type[512];
    char username[512];
    char password[512];
} user;

int main(void)
{
    FILE *file = fopen("test.txt","r");
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t linesize = 0;
    char *token;
    const char colon[2] = ":";
    const char space[2] = " ";
    
    user user_1;
    
    if (file) 
    {
        while (getline(&line, &linesize, file) != -1) 
        {
            printf("%s\n", line);
            
            token = strtok(line, colon);
            strcpy(user_1.type, token);
            
            token = strtok(NULL, space);
            strcpy(user_1.username, token);
            
            token = strtok(NULL, space);
            strcpy(user_1.password, token);
            
            printf("%s\n", user_1.type);
            printf("%s\n", user_1.username);
            printf("%s", user_1.password);
            free(line);
        }

        fclose(file);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

PS: There may be some flaws/bugs in above implementation, please consider the above code just as an example.

Comment: Note that the function `getline` is not part of ISO C. Is it a platform-specific function (in this case POSIX).

Comment: `user_1` is an uninitialised automatic variable. As written, `memcpy()` will leave `user_1.type` as an unterminated "string"... UB awaits...

Comment: @Fe2O3 rectified it. I guess now, people are gonna comment “use strncpy() instead of strcpy() to avoid potential buffer overrun” for security reasons

Comment: You can compile with two different versions of `strcpy()`?? Wow!!! (Further comment: Code posted as an answer should, at least, compile... Think about it...) re: `strncpy()`... Your answer as it stands is half way there... but could still overrun the buffer... if it compiled..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which reads one character at a time from the file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 200

int main( void )
{
    char type[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
    char user[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
    char pw[MAX_STRING_SIZE];

    FILE *fp;
    int ch;
    int i;

    //open the input file
    fp = fopen( "input.txt", "r" );
    if ( fp == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Error opening file!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //read first token
    i = 0;
    while ( ( ch = fgetc( fp ) ) != ':' )
    {
        if ( ch == EOF )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Input error!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        if ( i == MAX_STRING_SIZE )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Sub-string is too long!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        type[i++] = ch;
    }
    type[i] = '\0';

    //read second token
    i = 0;
    while ( ( ch = fgetc( fp ) ) != ' ' )
    {
        if ( ch == EOF )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Input error!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        if ( i == MAX_STRING_SIZE )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Sub-string is too long!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        user[i++] = ch;
    }
    user[i] = '\0';

    //read third token
    i = 0;
    while ( ( ch = fgetc( fp ) ) != EOF )
    {
        if ( i == MAX_STRING_SIZE )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Sub-string is too long!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        pw[i++] = ch;
    }
    pw[i] = '\0';

    //close the file
    fclose( fp );

    //print the three strings
    printf( "Type:%s\n", type );
    printf( "User:%s\n", user );
    printf( "Pw:%s\n", pw );
}
```

For the input stated in the question, this program has the desired output:

```
Type:Admin
User:Username
Pw:Password
```

Here is an alternative solution, which reads a whole line at once:

This solution reads a line from the file as a string, by using the function [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets). After doing that, it uses the function [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) to find the `':'` and `' '` delimiter characters in the string. Once they are found, the characters between the tokens can be copied so that they form a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 200

bool read_exactly_one_line( char buffer[], int buffer_size, FILE *fp );

int main( void )
{
    char type[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
    char user[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
    char pw[MAX_STRING_SIZE];

    FILE *fp;
    char line[500];
    char *p, *q;
    int token_length;

    //open the input file
    fp = fopen( "input.txt", "r" );
    if ( fp == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Error opening file!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //read one line of input
    if ( ! read_exactly_one_line( line, sizeof line, fp ) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "File is empty!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //find the delimiter between the first and second token
    p = strchr( line, ':' );
    if ( p == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Unable to find first delimiter!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //verify that first token is not too large
    token_length = p - line;
    if ( token_length >= MAX_STRING_SIZE )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Token too large!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //copy the first token
    memcpy( type, line, token_length );
    type[token_length] = '\0';

    //move pointer to start of second token
    p++;

    //find the delimiter between the second and third token
    q = strchr( p, ' ' );
    if ( q == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Unable to find second delimiter!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //verify that second token is not too large
    token_length = q - p;
    if ( token_length >= MAX_STRING_SIZE )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Token too large!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //copy the second token
    memcpy( user, p, token_length );
    user[token_length] = '\0';

    //move pointer to start of third token
    q++;

    //verify that third token is not too large
    token_length = strlen( q );
    if ( token_length >= MAX_STRING_SIZE )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Token too large!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //copy the third token
    memcpy( pw, q, token_length );
    pw[token_length] = '\0';

    //close the file
    fclose( fp );

    //print the three strings
    printf( "Type:%s\n", type );
    printf( "User:%s\n", user );
    printf( "Pw:%s\n", pw );
}

//This function will read exactly one line and remove the newline
//character, if it exists. On success, it will return true. If this
//function is unable to read any further lines due to end-of-file,
//it returns false. If it fails for any other reason, it will not
//return, but will print an error message and call "exit" instead.
bool read_exactly_one_line( char buffer[], int buffer_size, FILE *fp )
{
    char *p;

    //attempt to read one line from the stream
    if ( fgets( buffer, buffer_size, fp ) == NULL )
    {
        if ( ferror( fp ) )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Input error!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        return false;
    }

    //make sure that line was not too long for input buffer
    p = strchr( buffer, '\n' );
    if ( p == NULL )
    {
        //a missing newline character is ok if the next
        //character is a newline character or if we have
        //reached end-of-file (for example if the input is
        //being piped from a file or if the user enters
        //end-of-file in the terminal itself)
        if ( getc(fp) != '\n' && !feof(stdin) )
        {
            printf( "Line input was too long!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //remove newline character by overwriting it with a null
        //character
        *p = '\0';
    }

    return true;
}
```

This program has the same output as the first one.